# chats to be open for 24 hours before disappearing if the other side doesn't answer

Tags: getstream-chat

Does your solution allow by default or easily configured the chats to be open for 24 hours before disappearing if the other side doesn't answer?

I haven't had a try, but I want to know the posibility to do it since I am looking for a chat solution that allow me to do that